# Java web, jstl :Como executar um método no servlet ao sair de um input text ex:"verificar se a disponibilidade de nome para cadastro"

Tags: javascript, java, html, jstl

Como executar um método  ao sair de um `input` text. Exemplo vou fazer um cadastro no momento de me cadastrar  como usuário  quero verificar se aquele nome está disponível para ser utilizado , sendo que não pode aceitar usuários repetidos, para evitar que a verificação seja na hora de enviar todos os dados gostaria de fazer  essa verificação quando o usuário termine de digitar e passe ao próximo campo para preencher.

já fiz a parte do `Servlet` e do método `DAO` , mas a parte da `jsp` estou meio perdido vejo muita gente falando de `ajax`, mas gostaria de evitar de usar-lo.

**Meu servlet**

```
if(funcao.equals("verificaUsuario")){
    String usuario = request.getParameter("user");
    boolean verifica = log.verificarUsuario(usuario);

    if(verifica = true){
        request.setAttribute("O nome '"+usuario, "' este indisponível para uso, por gentileza tente outro nome para realizar o cadastro." );                
    }else{
        request.setAttribute("Prabéns! O nome '"+usuario, "' este disponível para uso." );                                
    }

    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("v_login_cad.jsp");                
    rd.forward(request, response);   
}
```

**meu DAO**

```
public boolean verificarUsuario(String nome) {
    String sql = "select * from login where log_nome=? ";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, nome);            
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //throw new RuntimeException("Erro 1_D   " + e);
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,"Erro 2_D  " + e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Creio que você não consiga fazer isso de modo seguro sem utilizar Javascript. No caso criar um endpoint para receber o dado do campo, no focusout desse campo faça um ajax assíncrono que envie o dado para seu endpoint valide e retorne um booleano.